# how to increment/decrement Hexadecimal value in C

Tags: c, hex, increment

I'm trying to create a counter using hex, I know this can easily be done using decimals, but is it possible to do this in hex, or is it the same in dec?

will it go like this?

```
myhex = 0x00;

myhex++;
```

or will it be done on an entirely different manner?

If you are asking why hex its because this is for an MCU and for me the best way to control the IO of MCU is using hex.

Comment: A variable does not contain a "hex number", it's just *a number*.

Comment: To clarify: hex is just a representation of a value. So you can work with hex values exactly the same as you would with decimal values (base 10.)

Comment: thank you for this valuable information. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes if you try it you will see it, that it makes no difference if the `number` is `hex`, `octal` or `decimal`!

As an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int myhex = 0x07;
    int myOct = 07;
    int myDec = 7;

    printf("Before increment:\n");
    printf("Hex: %x\n", myhex);
    printf("Oct: %o\n", myOct);
    printf("Dec: %d\n", myDec);

    myhex++;
    myOct++;
    myDec++;

    printf("After increment:\n");
    printf("Hex: %x\n", myhex);
    printf("Oct: %o\n", myOct);
    printf("Dec: %d\n", myDec);


  return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Before increment:
Hex: 7
Oct: 7
Dec: 7

After increment:
Hex: 8
Oct: 10
Dec: 8
```

Comment: Thank you! i have never really used hex that much in C before and have always assumed that the increment is only applicable for decimal values not for binary or hex, thanks for enlightening me. :)

Comment: @magicianIam Your welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: updated my answer with a better example!)